# Manually Populating select_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this looks insane, but I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def site_list
    @sites = []

    Dir.new(base_dir = "./app/sites/").each do |name, idx|
      path = "#{base_dir}#{name}"
      if FileTest.directory?(path) && !name.starts_with?('.')
        @sites << name
      end
    end

    return @sites
  end
```

Just stay with me through my craziness.

There's a URL parameter called `:site`, if this exists then I want a manually created on-the-fly drop down list to have the correct element selected. So, for this to work I need to create an associative-array/hash that does id > name.

Step-by-step:

1. List all the directories associating id > name (id is made up, it's just the index)
2. Based on the :site URL parameter, select the correct element in the select list
3. There is no step 3.

So you then have: `<%= select_tag :sites, options_for_select(site_list) %>` but with the third parameter as the option to select.

Hopefully this makes some sense at least!

**A description in English**

1. I am populating an array based on folders in the file system
2. This array is to populate a `select_tag`
3. The `select_tag`'s currently selected item is to be determined based on the current route. (`:site`)
4. If the route doesn't contain `:site` then display the `select_tag` with "Please select..." or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

In select form helper you can actually pass a hash and keys will be displayed in select menu and values will be the values. So let @sites be a hash, smth like this:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  @sites = { :site1 => 'stackoverflow', :site2 => 'someothersite' }
  ...
end
```

So to filter this hash with **site** get param let create a helper based on Hash#keep_if method http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def site_list(sites, site)
    sites.keep_if { |name, value| value == site }
  end
end
```

just change the condition in the block to work for you. And code in form will look like:<%

```
<% site = 'stackoverflow' %>
<%= site_list(@sites, site).inspect %>
<%= f.select :name, site_list(@sites, 'stackoverflow') %>
```

Even better way to do it without helper is to use before_filter in your controller:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :extract_select_option, :only => :your_action

  protected
  def extract_select_option
    # SITES - all sites readed from file
    @sites = SITES.keep_if { |key, value| value == params[:site] }
  end
end
```

Comment: I thought it was barfing at me because it expected an integer value, which would seem weird. Yes, I could build the hash, I need to figure out a way to cache it though (non-DB). This looks awesome, I'll take a look at it in a couple of hours.